# App is not moving to next activity while all the permission is granted

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am properly allowing and denying permission and app is running properly first time but when all permission is granted and next time when user launches the app, it shows only splash screen and become stable and do not move to next activity , and it also not give any error , what i am trying is below.

```
 private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 5;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    splashIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashIcon);
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.bounce);
            splashIcon.setAnimation(anim1);
            anim1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    {
                        checkMultiplePermissions();
                    }else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,UserGuideActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
                {
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
private void checkMultiplePermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
        }
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        {
            permissionsNeeded.add("Read Storage");
        }
        if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS))
        {
            permissionsNeeded.add("Read Sms");
        }
        if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        {
            permissionsNeeded.add("Read Contacts");
        }
        if(!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG))
        {
            permissionsNeeded.add("Read Calllogs");
        }

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0)
        {
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
}



private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)

        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);

            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // All Permissions Granted
                startActivity(new Intent(this,UserGuideActivity.class));
                finish();
                return;
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please permit all the permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: You simple check all permission is granted or not : if(grantResults.length==permissions.length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because if all permissions are granted then this will be `false` and there is no `else` case to do anything

```
    if (permissionsList.size() > 0)
    {
        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
```

so it should be like this

```
    if (permissionsList.size() > 0)
    {
        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
    else{
          startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,UserGuideActivity.class));
                        finish();
    }
```

Improvements : you can eliminate creating map and loop by making reuse of `checkMultiplePermissions` function but modification will be required at other places accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Check this condition :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
{
    checkMultiplePermissions();
}else{
    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,UserGuideActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Nothing will happen after checkMultiplePermissions() is run, so you need to add startActivity there only when permissions are granted.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

As you described in your question that it is working first time and you are giving all permissions. So according to your code **if all permissions are granted** it will **not go to** `onRequestPermissionsResult`. And you have written your Intent part in that method so it will stick to same screen.
Add else statement as stated by **Pavneet**

Answer (score 0):

Try to create method to check is all permission is granted or not if not granted then it will automatically ask each permission additional pass `isAllPermissionRequired` flag to use same method on `onRequestPermissionsResult` if you not required all permission move another screen

```
private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 121;

private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(boolean isAllPermissionRequired) {
        int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        int readStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int readSmsPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        int readContactPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        int readCallLogPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (readStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (readSmsPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        }

        if (readContactPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        }

        if (readCallLogPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            if(isAllPermissionRequired) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {
         if (checkAndRequestPermissions(false)) {
             startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,UserGuideActivity.class));
             finish();
         } 
    }
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if(checkAndRequestPermissions(true)){
       startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,UserGuideActivity.class));
       finish();
   }
}
```

Note : Above sample i have pass `isAllPermissionRequired` = `true` from `onCreate` to ask for each permission and `isAllPermissionRequired` = `false` from `onRequestPermissionsResult` to not ask any permission even user not grant but you need to pass `isAllPermissionRequired` = `true` in `onRequestPermissionsResult` if required all permission mandatory.